# How to filter by color using XML-RPC and Python

Tags: api, soap

I'm using "python-magento 0.3.3" to fetch products from Magento Enterprise 1.13.0.2 via XML-RPC. Getting an unfiltered list works. Filtering by 'sku' or 'description' works. However I cannot filter by color or by a custom attribute.

```
    # these are ok
    args = {'sku': {'like': '93%'}}
    args = {'sku': {'eq': '9365427'}}
    args = {'description': {'like': 'The%'}}

    # this returns []
    args = {'color': {'like': 'Bla%'}}

    # actual call
    return magento.catalog_product.list(args)
```

Can I filter by these? Is there a special format for the custom filter?

Answer (score 1):

Aha! One must use the ID not the label or name of the color attribute.

```
    args = {'color': {'eq': '16'}}
```

By the way, 'is' instead of 'eq' doesn't work even though some docs mention it.